# Prevent calling parent route ngOnInit method for any child component test

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing tests for my angular component. I have one parent component and a child component. In parent component's ngOnInit I am calling a back-end function which require authentication. While testing child component I do not want to load or I want to prevent ngOnInit of parent component.

A part of my routes look like:

```
{
    path: 'core',
    component: CoreComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { 
            path: 'endpoint',
            component: EndpointComponent,
            children: [
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'machine', pathMatch: 'full' },
                { path: 'machine', component: MachineComponent }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I am testing MachineComponent. And In CoreComponent's ngOnInit I am calling back-end function. And I want to prevent this while testing MachineComponent.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getMyDetails();
}
```

My test class look like:

```
describe('MachineComponent', () => {
  let component: MachineComponent;
  let endpointService: EndpointService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MachineComponent>;

  let ep_data: any = {"name":"machine_ep"};

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'machine', component: MachineComponent }])
      ],
      declarations: [ MachineComponent ],
      providers: [
        EndpointService
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MachineComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    endpointService = TestBed.get(EndpointService);
    spyOn(endpointService, 'getEndpoints').and.returnValue(of([ep_data]));
  });

  it('should get endpoints', () => {
    component.getEndpoints();
    expect(component.endpoints[0].name).toBe("machine_ep");
    expect(endpointService.getEndpoints).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

In my interceptor I am redirecting to login route if any service call fail with 401 code.

My test is failing with error:

```
HeadlessChrome 70.0.3538 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
```

How I can escape out of this error?

Comment: Does MachineComponent explicitly extend CoreComponent, or is CoreComponent just a parent component communicating with Inputs and Outputs?

Comment: No It do not extends.